# Magento - Add-to-cart querystring replaces cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

For some reason, when I have a product in the cart, and then click on an add-to-cart querystring (store.com/store/checkout/cart/add?product=622&qty;=1&super;_group[249]=1) from an email, it creates a whole new cart and loses the previous products.  I guess it creates a whole new session. Is there anyway I can keep the previous products in the cart? I'm using magento 1.4.2.

Comment: where you logged in after you were transferred to card from email link?

Comment: No, I have customer logins disabled. Everything is done as guest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. There's a difference between store.com and www.store.com when it comes to sessions. If I use www in the querystring, it works fine.

Comment: Oh the woes of cookies and SSL when it comes to www vs non-www.  Simple trick is to redirect this in the .htaccess file.  Saves a lot of headaches in the future too.